# Can A3C be applied for training TD3?

Tags: python, pytorch

How to use the Asynchronous RL Framework(like A3C) to train the DDPG or TD3?

I have tried each actor-learner as a DDPG agent and asynchronous update the global DDPG agent, but it didn't work.

Comment: any updates on this?